# Laravel on cpanel Shared host could not find driver

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, cpanel

I have a website on shared hosting developed with laravel, it was working perfect before but suddenly it started show these eror

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from `portfolios` order by `created_at` desc limit 10)

Comment: thats because sql is not defined, i guse your default driver is sql but mysql is not install correctly in your hosting